# Emulate high resolution graphics chip in Windows 3.1 on Dosbox

Tags: graphics-card, dosbox, high-resolution, windows-3.1

I am running Windows 3.1 within Dosbox 0.74. I have the resolution at 1024x768 256 colors. I would like to use a higher resolution. I have done a lot of googling, but I'm having trouble finding a clear answer. I suppose what I want to do is emulate a graphics card from the era which was capable of a higher resolution like 1600x1200. I would be fine with 16 colors, just want the higher resolution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

DOSBox supports standard VGA graphics (which is probably what you are using). BUT.. it also supports some other types of graphics. By default, it’s set up to emulate S3 Graphics.

I would suggest trying [this](https://www.vogonsdrivers.com/files/downloader.php?fileid=1702) driver (S3 Virge).  It supports 1600x1200.  You might need to play with which of the 8 1600x1200 entries work.

If it doesn't work, you will need to ***look for another S3 driver*** but it *should* work.

You need to realize (if you weren't around), 1600x1200 was the thing of dreams back in the Win3.1 days.  NOBODY I knew (and I am indeed a nerd) had anything close to that.  1024x768 was already a resolution higher than 99 percent of people could support.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The dosbox machine is set to svga_s3, and after testing each of the 8 versions of 1600x1200 on the list, I am not able to boot windows. The splash screen comes up, and then I get a message at the DOS prompt saying "the selected display driver does not support current graphics chip." I guess that means I will have to find a different S3 driver?

Haha I remember how things were. Last time I ran windows 3.1 on real hardware it was my 486/66 DX with 4MB RAM. No way was that thing gonna run anything much beyond 800x600.

Comment: Update - today I got 1600x1200 @256 colors with small fonts working. I decided to try DOSbox-X instead of 0.74. I also decided to try the S3 drivers from the following link: [link] (http://www.sierrahelp.com/Utilities/Emulators/DOSBox/3x_InstallGraphicsDrivers.html#S3)
This combination worked for me.

Comment: AWESOME!  If my post got you there, please feel free to accept it.  Also, feel free to fill in what you had to do and where you had to go.  I am glad you got this.  It will help people in the future.